# Laravel Dusk: how to delete all data between sessions

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

Between test runs (e.g. individual `php artisan dusk` commands) the browser is storing that the user from a previous test is still logged in. This just started happening today, when I had to re-install dusk due to a ChromeDriver issue.

In my DuskTestCase file I have this, which I believe previously was working:

```
    protected function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();
        foreach (static::$browsers as $browser) {
            $browser->driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
        }
    }
```

However, when I run tests, and add a breakpoint to `$browser->driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();` it never hits this point as `static::$browsers` is an array of 0.

It then opens the browser and tries to run the test (in this case Register a new user), but it can't because a user is already logged in from the previous test.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44907379/1033654 ?

Comment: @Rwd yeah, I can see that session()->flush(); gets hit once the tests have finished, but when I run the tests again, the user is still logged in.